# How to load CSS file in qooxdoo dynamically

Tags: css, qooxdoo, dynamic-script-loading

Is there a special *qooxdoo* class to load CSS files dynamically like `qx.util.DynamicScriptLoader` does for JavaScript files?

For example, depends on user choice what geo maps he wants to use an application loads specific JavaScript and CSS files. I can get `.js` file via `qx.util.DynamicScriptLoader` class but for css I use `externalResources` section in `Manifest.json` file which always loads a style file (am I right?).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A dynamic possibility to include css files, e.g. in the constructor of a class, is using `qx.bom.Stylesheet.includeFile` like this:

```js
qx.bom.Stylesheet.includeFile("https://myserver.com/my.css");
```

This way I've successfully built completely dynamic wrappers for packages/frameworks where all external resources are loaded only on wrapper class instantiation in conjunction with `qx.util.DynamicScriptLoader`.

If the css files are within your projects resources, you have to call `qx.util.ResourceManager.getInstance().toUri()` on the resource name and feed it then into `qx.bom.Stylesheet.includeFile`.

Lets say you have a css file in your project in `resource/myframework/my.css` you have to first create an `@asset` hint like this in your wrapper class:

```js
/*
 * @asset(myframework/my.css)
 */
```

and afterwards, e.g. in the constructor you call:

```js
  qx.bom.Stylesheet.includeFile(qx.util.ResourceManager.getInstance().toUri(
    "resource/myframework/my.css"
  ));
```

In order to avoid multiple loading of the css file, I've added a static class member `CSS_INCLUDED` to the wrapper class, initialized to false and then set to true after calling `qx.bom.Stylesheet.includeFile` which results in the this code:

```js
  if(my.wrapper.CSS_INCLUDED === false) {
    qx.bom.Stylesheet.includeFile(qx.util.ResourceManager.getInstance().toUri(
      "resource/myframework/my.css"
    ));
    my.wrapper.CSS_INCLUDED = true;
  }
```

This way subsequent instantiations do not load the css file again.

Comment: Is there a way to be notified if `qx.bom.Stylesheet.includeFile` failed or succeeded?   `qx.util.DynamicScriptLoader` class has these special events. I know  `qx.bom.Stylesheet.includeFile` is static and no return value but maybe other classes/methods do this work.

Comment: `qx.bom.Stylesheet.includeFile` creates a dom node of type link and sets the `type` to `css/text`, `rel` to `stylesheet` and `href` to the URL of the css file and adds it then to the documents head section. You could also do this yourself manually and assign  `onload` and `onerror` event handlers to that link element. It may also be desirable to have a `qx.util.DynamicCSSFileLoader` with a similar interface as offered by `qx.utilDynamicScriptLoader`. But it does not exist yet.